# Sharepoint Online executeQueryAsync JSOM - Return Value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Using Sharepoint Online 2013 building an app using JSOM.
This current part is after the submission of data to a list (Which is working correctly) a modal will open allowing users to create a PDF off that List and other Lists. The current issue is that the data from the list must be ready on the client side before I can begin making it into a PDF, I have read over the literature on the "Promise" method and that is what I have been trying recently with little success.

`function getQuoteDetails() {`

```
var d = $.Deferred(function(){

    var ListName = "Quote";
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var lstObject = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //var _valuetofind = $('#QuoteID').text();
    var _valuetofind = '1';
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><ViewFields>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_ID' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='CPY_ID' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='CUST_ID' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_RaiseDate' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_DueDate' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_Price' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_GST' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_TotalPrice' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_PurchaseOrder' />" +
        "</ViewFields>" +
        "<Query><Where><Contains>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Q_ID'/>" +
        "<Value Type='Number'>" + _valuetofind + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>");

    var listItemCollection = lstObject.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(listItemCollection, "Include(Q_ID, CPY_ID, CUST_ID, Q_RaiseDate, Q_DueDate, Q_Price, Q_GST, Q_TotalPrice, Q_PurchaseOrder)");
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetItemsSuccess, onGetItemsFail);

    function onGetItemsSuccess(sender, args) {
        var listItemEnumerator = listItemCollection.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var quotearray = [];

            quotearray['Q_ID'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Q_ID');
            quotearray['CPY_ID'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('CPY_ID');
            quotearray['CUST_ID'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('CUST_ID');
            quotearray['Q_RasiedDate'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Q_RasiedDate');
            quotearray['Q_DueDate'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Q_DueDate');
            quotearray['Q_Price'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Q_Price');
            quotearray['Q_GST'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Q_GST');
            quotearray['Q_TotalPrice'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Q_TotalPrice');
            quotearray['Q_PurchaseOrder'] = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Q_PurchaseOrder');
        }
        d.resolve(quotearray);

    }

    function onGetItemsFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get items. Error: ' + args.get_message());
    }

});
return d.promise();
```

`}`

This code is then called by:

`function CreateQuotePDF() {`

```
getQuoteDetails().done(function (quotearray) {
    var quotedetails = quotearray;
    alert('Nothing'); <---- quotedetails is undefined at this point
});
```

alert('Nothing'); <---- quotedetails is undefined at this point
`}`

Hope you can help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some recommendations**

- make sure you are using jQuery version >= **1.5** since `Deferred` object
  was introduced in jQuery 1.5
- there is **no** need to specify CAML `ViewFields` and value for the second parameter of `SP.ClientContext.load` function *at the same time* since both of them are used for specifying what properties to retrieve
- always prefer to include *failed callback* for [SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx) function in order to handle any occurred error

Having said that i would suggest you the below more generic method for getting list items:

```
function getListItems(listTitle,propertiesToInclude)
{ 
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list =  web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
   var includeExpr = 'Include(' + propertiesToInclude.join(',') + ')';
   ctx.load(items,includeExpr); 
   var d = $.Deferred();
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       var result = items.get_data().map(function(i){
           return i.get_fieldValues();   
       });
       d.resolve(result);
   },
   function(sender,args){
       d.reject(args);
   });
   return d.promise();
}
```

In that case list items could be retrieved as shown below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

   var listTitle = 'Documents';  //set list title here
   var properties = ['Title','ID'];  //specify items properties here
   getListItems(listTitle,properties)
   .done(function(items){
      console.log(items);
   })
   .fail(function(error){
      console.log(error.get_message()); //if any error is occurred?
    });

});
```

Comment: This looks good, that generic framework will reduce code a fair bit. Though I have a few questions for you around it. if you noticed the CAML query. the ' "<Query><Where><Contains> <FieldRef Name='Q_ID'/>" is very important as I need to only return certain values and the lists can be quite large (900+) because of this I was worried that returning the entire list in an array could be quite slow. - Can I ask in your first what does i return a named array or?

Comment: Regarding `ViewFields`,  propertiesToInclude parameter of`SP.ClientContext.load(clientObject,propertiesToInclude)` serves the same purpose, in particular to explicitly specify what properties to  retrieve

Comment: I was more talking about specifying a WHERE clause in the data retrieval process. But I can just get the whole array and use jquery to weed out the non-results